# How to reload the table view after dismissing a modal

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm currently having the user input data on a modal and save it to Core Data:

```swift
var container: NSPersistentContainer!

func saveContext() {
    if container.viewContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("An error occured whlie saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Upon dismissing the modal, I want to reload the table on the parent view controller. But, no matter how I load it, from viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, the table doesn't get reloaded. I know that the data is properly saved into Core Data because when I rebuild, the data gets properly displayed on the table.

This is the function I want to trigger upon dismissing the modal:

```swift
func loadSavedData() {
    if fetchedResultsController == nil {
        let request = Goal.createFetchRequest()
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        request.fetchBatchSize = 20
        
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: container.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "title", cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    }
    
    fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = myPredicate
    
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("Fetch failed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [article](https://medium.com/livefront/why-isnt-viewwillappear-getting-called-d02417b00396) of Sean Berry published in Medium, you can know more about the reason why viewWillAppear is not called.

Then, you can use a closure to know when your modal is dismissed.

Add it in your modal view controller:

```
var isDismissed: (() -> Void)?
```

Then you can call it when you dismiss the controller:

```
self.isDismissed?()
```

Finally in the presenting view controller, when you init your modal, you can listen for the closure, for example:

```
let modalController = YourController()
modalController.isDismissed = { [weak self] in
   self?.loadSavedData()
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Swift. is `() -> Void)` a placeholder? If it is, what should take its place? Also, the presenting view controller is a UITableViewController. Where should I place `modalController.isDismissed {}`? Would it be within the same function as where instantiate the modal and present it?

Comment: No worries, regarding your first question have a look at the [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html), and no it’s not a placeholder and going through the documentation you can learn more about it. For the second question yes, you have to place it where you instantiate and present your modal :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying `dismiss(animated: true, completion:  { self.isDismissed?() } )` within the modal, but `vc.isDismissed { [weak self] _ in self?.loadSavedData() }` is giving me an error that says `Cannot call value of non-function type '(() -> Void)?`

Comment: I get an error `Argument passed to call that takes no arguments` without the underscore

Comment: @Kevvv You are right, writing from mobile I missed it. It is `vc.isDismissed = { [weak self] in }` and in this block you will receive the callback when your modal will be dismissed. The () -> Void closure means that we haven’t parameters as input nor output.

Comment: Nice :) Happy to help!